# Cannot access emit property while testing click event on Vue 3

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to test a component with Vue test-utils, but I'm having trouble when I try to test a click on a imported component.

This is my test file:

```js
  import { Table, Input } from 'ant-design-vue';
  import { CheckOutlined, EditOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons-vue';
  
  import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(TableEditable, {
      global: {
        components: {
          'a-table': Table,
          'a-input': Input,
          'check-outlined': CheckOutlined,
          'edit-outlined': EditOutlined,
        }
      },
      emits: ['edit', 'save'],
      props: {
        tableData: {
          "data":[
            {"id":"0","monday":"0"}],
          "columns":[
            {"title":"Mon","dataIndex":"monday","slots":{"customRender":"monday"}}]
        },
        dataSrc: [{"id":"0","monday":"0","tuesday":"0","wednesday":"0","thursday":"0","friday":"0","saturday":"9","sunday":"10","key":"0"}]
      }
    })
  })
  
  describe('first test', () => {
    it('first test: check if theres a class name', () => {
      expect(wrapper.classes()).toContain('tableEditable')
    })
    it('click and emit buttons', async () => {
        await wrapper.findComponent({ref: 'edit-outlined'})
        await wrapper.trigger('click')
        expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('edit')
  
      })
  })
```

This is my component:

```html
  <template>
     <a-table bordered :data-source="dataSrc" :columns="tableData.columns" :pagination="false" class="tableEditable">
      <template #title>
        <div class="formLayoutCrud">
          <p>{{this.title}}</p>
          <input-multiple-button :name="'buttonOptions'" :value="'percentage'" :options="this.buttonOptions"> </input-multiple-button>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template v-for="col in this.editableCells" #[col]="{ column, text, record }" :key="col">
        <div class="editable-cell">
          <div v-if="editableTableData[record.key + '|' + column.key] !== undefined" class="editable-cell-input-wrapper">
            <a-input v-model:value="editableTableData[record.key + '|' + column.key]" @pressEnter="save(record.key, column.key)" type="number" />
            <check-outlined class="editable-cell-icon-check" @click="save(record.key, column.key)" />
          </div>
          <div v-else class="editable-cell-text-wrapper">
            {{ text || ' ' }}
            <edit-outlined class="editable-cell-icon" @click="edit(record.key, column.key)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </a-table>
  </template>
  <script>
  
  import { CheckOutlined, EditOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons-vue';
  
  import InputMultipleButton from '@/components/crudForm/InputMultipleButton.vue';
  
  export default {
    name: 'TableEditable',
    props: {
      title: String,
      buttonOptions: Array,
      editableCells: Array,
      tableData: Object,
      dataSrc: Array,
      editableDataProp: Object
    },
    emits: ['edit', 'save'],
    components: {
      CheckOutlined,
      EditOutlined,
      InputMultipleButton
    },
    data(){
      return {
        editableTableData: this.editableDataProp
      }
    },
    methods: {
      edit(row, column) {
        this.$emit('edit', row, column)
      },
      save(row, column) {
        this.$emit('save', row, column)
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  <style>
```

And this is the error I get when I run npm test

```
  > vue-cli-service test:unit "TableEditable.spec.js"
  
   FAIL  tests/unit/components/crudForm/TableEditable.spec.js
    checkbox first tests
    ✓ first test: check if theres a class name (18ms)
    ✕ click and emit buttons (7ms)
  
    ● checkbox first tests › click and emit buttons
  
    expect(received).toHaveProperty(path)
  
    Expected path: "edit"
    Received path: []
  
    Received value: {"click": [[{"isTrusted": false}]]}
  
      38 |       // await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
      39 |       await wrapper.trigger('click')
    > 40 |       expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('edit')
       |                     ^
      41 |
      42 |     })
      43 | })
  
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/components/crudForm/TableEditable.spec.js:40:39)
  
  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
  Tests:     1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
  Snapshots: 0 total
  Time:      4.653s
  Ran all test suites matching /TableEditable.spec.js/i.
```

As I said, sorry if this is a simple error but I'm starting to learn tests so I don't have a lot of experience. If someone needs more information please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('edit')` should work.

So I think the issue is that the click is not working as you expect

you have

```js
await wrapper.findComponent({ref: 'edit-outlined'})
await wrapper.trigger('click')
```

which will

- find the `edit-outlined` button in the wrapper
- click on the component/wrapper (NOT the button)

to fix that, you can try chaining it like this:

```js
await wrapper
  .findComponent({ref: 'edit-outlined'})
  .trigger('click');
```

The trigger here is assigned to the result of `findComponent`

### Update

I believe `wrapper.findComponent({ref: 'edit-outlined'})` is not finding the component. When using `ref` it will look for components that have that value in the ref attribute.

you have

```html
<div v-else class="editable-cell-text-wrapper">
  {{ text || ' ' }}
  <edit-outlined class="editable-cell-icon" @click="edit(record.key, column.key)" />
</div>
```

`edit-outlined` is the name/type of the component, and not a ref.

you could change it to

```html
<div v-else class="editable-cell-text-wrapper">
  {{ text || ' ' }}
  <edit-outlined ref="edit-outlined" class="editable-cell-icon" @click="edit(record.key, column.key)" />
</div>
```

which would put it into `this.$refs` internal object (`this.$refs['edit-outlined']` specifically) which would make it accessible using  `wrapper.findComponent({ref: 'edit-outlined'})`.

You should also be able to change the way you target that element which should make it work without changing the code you are testing.

[findcomponent](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/findComponent.html#findcomponent) has three type you can pass as the selector argument.

> `{Component|ref|string} selector`

If you only have one instance or `EditOutlined`, you can target that using the `Component` type like this:

```js
const btn = wrapper.findComponent(EditOutlined);
expect(btn.exists()).toBe(true);
await btn.trigger('click');
```

also, it's a good idea to add these: `expect(btn.exists()).toBe(true);` They *also* act as a "sanity test" and make sure when you get an error that you are looking in the right place.

Comment: Still not working and gives me the same error. :/ Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I think I see what's going on. I believe `{ref: 'edit-outlined'}` does not do what you think it does. I will update answer.

Comment: I've tried both possible solutions and it didn't work, also tried with #id but it doesn't work too. I don't know what to do, but thanks for the answers.

Comment: you could try console.logging the wrapper's `.html()` response. That might help with the debugging.